# JQuery UI sortable what value is what?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am so confused about this JQuery UI that I don't even know what things represents what. I have this code:

```
// Iterate over all of the list items
    $("#sortable").children('ul li').each(function(index, item){

 // Set each items "alt" attribute to it's corresponding spot in the list.
 // Added +1 so that it uses numbers 1-7 instead of 0-6
    $("#house_wall1").children($item).attr('alt', index + 1)
```

And the only thing I am asking for, is an explanation of, what `index` and `item` shall represent in this example. Is `item` or `index` some predefined variables in the API? Or is this variables I'll have to define myself? And in such case, what variable shall be what? I am trying to change some images `alt` value by having a list with the images name on, and the `alt` value is going to represent their spot in the list.

Thanks in advance, I am really confused.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but `item` and `$item` is definitively not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the method `each` in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) passes 2 properties, the `indexInArray` of the loop and the `valueOfElement`.

this is the same as:

```
var items = [ ... ];
for(index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    var item = items[index];
}
```

so, `index` it's your current index (array index starts with `0`) and the item, it's the current item.

In you case, you're calling your `function` for each node that was found with `$("#sortable").children('ul li')`, in other words, all `<li>` elements of `<ul>` that are `children` of an element with id `sortable`...

Does it make sense? if not, this is line by line:

```
$("#sortable")                   // find the element that has id = sortable
    .children('ul li')           // in that sortable element, find all <li>
    .each(                       // for each element found do:
       function(index, item)     // as this an abbreviation of a for loop,
       {                         // use index and item
            $("#house_wall1")    // find the element with id = house_wall1
              .children($item)   // find the item (this case, it's an <li>)
              .attr('alt', index + 1) // set the attribute alt to index+1
       }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! This was really genious and it seems soooo much more clear what I am doing now. I really appreciate it, thumps up!